# Ubuntu root sound problem

Tags: sound, root

Hello i just installed ubuntu 12.10 and made a new root account
the problem is that in the normal user the audio works fine
but when i log in as root the audio doesn't work ( muted and i can't change it ).
can anyone help me?

Comment: amm? what do you mean by root account? You can not login to root accounts in linux by GUI way? What audio does not work? The audio of song or system sound?

Comment: i created a root account and logged out then clicked log in then typed the username root and the password that i made, the icon that is in the top right, when i click it i can't change change the volume.

Comment: I hope you know that gui login as root is not recommeneded. I hope you know what risk you are taking. This is serious security risk and highly discouraged.

Comment: Could you tell me what is the risk please?

Comment: Risk? Every single thing on your system.

Comment: Ok now i understand thank you i will not login as root again

Comment: Logging in as root makes it easier for intruders (however they choose to intrude) to get access to important system files, making your machine more vulnerable to the few Linux viruses out there, as since you are root and they are carrying out their actions as you, they have access to EVERYTHING.

Answer (score 10):

Click on "Dash Home" in the top left corner of the screen. Type in "Startup Applications" in the search bar.

When it shows up open it. Click on "Add" and put in `/usr/bin/pulseaudio` in the command section. You can put in "Pulsaudio" or whatever you want for the name and click on "Save". Log out and back in and the sound will work.

Everyone knows logging in as root is not recommended, but that's not a reason for not answering the question.

Comment: +1 for "Everyone knows logging in as root is not recommended, but that's not a reason for not answering the question."